# App.root must be an _instance_ of Widget. Invalid instance in App.root

Tags: python, kivy

I'm not exactly new to python but wouldn't I know it well and fully, but I'm completely new to Kivy. It's just a small thing I'm doing just to start somewhere. I'm working in Visual Studio Code(VSC). Python version 3.10. The idea is: there are 5 buttons, each button has a name, when you click on a button, image(meme) should show up. Here is the full code, terminal, debugger and what is in command prompt:

**code**
[code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HOugz.png)

**Terminal**
[Terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Diygw.png)

**Debugger**
[Debugger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ycKTV.jpg)

**Command Prompt**
[Command Prompt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n74fy.jpg)

**Here is python itself and a folder "Projects"**
C:\Users\Кирилл\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Python 3.10
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XV963.jpg)

**Here is folder with virtual environment(App_EPQ) and a folder with code(App_code)**
C:\Users\Кирилл\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Python 3.10\Projects
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YMJEA.jpg)

Thanks in advance

Tried to rewrite the code but that didn't work. Tried to find someone with a similar problem no luck there also. No idea what to do next and how to fix it so this is my last hope.

Answer (score 0):

Your class has to inherit a layout as well as App:

```
    class HBoxLayoutExample(BoxLayout, App)
```

Another way to do it would be to create a class that builds the app and returns the layout:

```
    class HBoxLayoutExample(BoxLayout)
    **your code**

    class HBoxApp(App):
        def build(self):
            return HBoxLayoutExample
    if __name__ == '__main__':
        HBoxApp().run()
```

as shown here https://kivy.org/doc/stable/guide/lang.html#designing-with-the-kivy-language

Answer (score 0):

Replace your line:

```
return layout, button
```

with:

```
return layout
```

That's all. `build()` method have to return one widget, which in your case is BoxLayout instance.